# Kill xfs_io processes

Tags: centos, process, kill

I have an EC2 instance running CentOS 5.6 86_64. I use xfs_freeze to freeze/thaw a file system before taking a snapshot. Normally this works great, but today it stopped working - the freeze operation never finished. I checked the process list and found a handful of `xfs_io` processes running that seem to be stuck:

```
  337 pts/0    D      0:00 /usr/sbin/xfs_io -r -p xfs_freeze -x -c freeze /var/lib/pgsql
32138 pts/0    D      0:00 /usr/sbin/xfs_io -r -p xfs_freeze -x -c freeze /var/lib/pgsql
32228 pts/0    D      0:00 /usr/sbin/xfs_io -r -p xfs_freeze -x -c freeze /var/lib/pgsql
32261 pts/0    D      0:00 /usr/sbin/xfs_io -r -p xfs_freeze -x -c freeze /var/lib/pgsql
32305 ?        D      0:00 /usr/sbin/xfs_io -r -p xfs_freeze -x -c freeze /var/lib/pgsql
```

`kill -TERM` and `kill -9` don't seem to kill these processes off. I really don't want to reboot the machine, because it happens to be a primary database server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If kill -9 doesn't work, it's likely the thread is in a kernel call and the kernel is blocking the SIGINT.  You can't kill threads/processes in that state.  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/8357) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223727/858702) explain why.

Essentially, you most likely need to reboot.